# When can the work performed by subsystems not equal the total work by the system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

In his $Thermodynamics$, Fermi mentions the following:

> “The entropy of a system composed of several parts is very often equal to the sum of the entropies of all the parts. This is true if the energy of the system is the sum of the energies of all the parts and if the work performed by the system during a transformation is equal to the sum of
>   the amounts of work performed by all the parts.”

I understand that the sum of energies might not equal the total because of the inter-particle attractions.

I suspect that the presence of forces which violate Newton’s third law are sufficient to make the sum of works not to equal to the total work.
Am I correct?

Comment: Every time you refer to Fermi it would be helpful if you gave PDF page so that it can be looked at in context

Comment: I think the question is self-sufficient.

Comment: sorry to bother

Comment: what are the "...forces which violate Newton’s third law..." you are thinking of?

Comment: @Bob_D  ....   page 53

Comment: @hyportnex Like the Lorentz force.

Comment: why would the Lorentz force not satisfy action-reaction? any electric  motor I have ever seen needed to be bolted down to exert any torque.

Comment: @hyportnex So when can it be violated? The equality of the sum of works and the total work.

Comment: Fermi, page 53: "Thus, for example, in the case of a system composed of two homogeneous substances, it will be possible to express the energy as the sum of the energies of the two substances only if we can neglect the surface energy of the two substances where they are in contact. The surface energy can generally be neglected only if the two substances are not very finely subdivided; otherwise, it can play a considerable role."

Comment: Yes I read that. But I'm looking for a corresponding example for work, not energy.

Comment: the sum of all "works" is *not* work instead it is the difference between the change of (internal energy + kinetic energy) and the heat transferred from/to the environment, that is all you can know.